# How do I execute a php script from javascript from D3.js?

Tags: javascript, php, file, d3.js

I have a php script which creates a certain file for me.
I'd like to execute my script somewhere in my D3 or JS code. How can I do this?

Comment: possible duplicate of [jQuery Ajax POST example with PHP](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5004233/jquery-ajax-post-example-with-php)

Answer (score 0):

This is really easy done using AJAX (Form of JavaScript). You can use AJAX to call PHP script, execute it and then the result is returned.

Have a look here:-
http://www.tutorialspoint.com/php/php_and_ajax.htm